# How to load springboot custom test configuration for particular tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

I have two spring junit tests that require different configurations. These are as follows

```
package some.pkg.name;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Test1.ContextConfig.class})
public class Test1 {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // do something
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("some.pkg.name")
    public static class ContextConfig {
        // bean definitions here
    }
}


package some.pkg.name;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Test2.ContextConfig.class})
public class Test2 {

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        // do something
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class ContextConfig {
        // bean definitions here
    }
}
```

When I run `Test1` I end up with Test1's beans AND Test2's beans. I've been at it for a while but can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong? I've tried putting the config classes in their own package but it hasn't worked. In `Test1` I need spring's component scan, in `Test2` the beans are created "by hand". The default component scan for the project is `some.pkg`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by putting the configuration classes outside of the component scan, like so:

```
package some.pkg.name;

import some.config.ContextConfigTest1;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ContextConfigTest1.class)
public class Test1 {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // do something
    }

}


package some.pkg.name;

import some.config.ContextConfigTest2;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ContextConfigTest2.class)
public class Test2 {

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        // do something
    }
}


package some.config;

@Configuration
public class ContextConfigTest2 {
    // bean definitions here
}

package some.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("some.pkg.name")
public class ContextConfigTest1 {
    // bean definitions here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need spring main application component scan beans then don't specify the custom configuration on that test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class Test1 {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
       // do something
    }

}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Test2.ContextConfig.class})
public class Test2 {

    @Test
    public void test2() {
       // do something
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class ContextConfig {
      // bean definitions here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer; I tried it and it didn't work, the beans I need aren't found without the component scan.

Comment: probably they might be in different packages where that package might not be under `component scan` can you show the error message with stack trace in the post @WilliamBurnham

Comment: It was a component scan problem. I fixed it by putting the configuration classes in their own package, outside of the "component scan" package. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can accept my answer it that helps @WilliamBurnham

Comment: It's not what solved the problem but it pointed me in the right direction (I upvoted). The problem was that Test2's `@Configuration` classs got picked up by the component scan.